# Laravel 5.6 404 event

Tags: php, laravel, content-management-system, http-status-code-404

I've been going round in circles on this.

We wrote a CMS system in Laravel 3 using a bundle.
Time has come to develop a new one using latest Lavarel 5.6 and that mean packages.

We want to be able to define our own routes in web.php but everything that is not defined is picked up by the CMS package routes file so it can check if there is a page defined in the CMS and return the correct view.

In L3 this we did:

```
Event::override('404', function() {
    ...magic
```

In laravel 5.6 you can't do this so i've tried all sorts of:

```
Route::any('/{any}', function ($url = false) {
})->where('any', '.*');
```

But the issue is Laravel loads *all* the routes files in memory and the /{any} route overrides any of the routes defined in web.php, regardless of the order the service providers are loaded and we want to allow routes to be defined but to mop up anything that is not already defined.

In L4 it looks like you used to be able to do this:

```
App::missing(function($e) {
```

But again that's not possible in L5

I could possibly run it though an exception handler, but I want this to work in the package so its easily installable, and I haven't been able to make this work either!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you define this route last, it should work.

Comment: No it doesn't in fact loading it last is what overrides all the other routes. This is because laravel loads all routes together in memory.

Answer (score -1):

`// other routes redirected to login
    Route::get('/{any}', function () {
        return redirect('/login');
    })->where('any', '.*s');`

try this route

Comment: Thats the same as my code - and it doesn't work - it overrides any other defined routes